# CSS: active class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to experiment with a simple CSS menu with a background as follows:

```css
body {
  background-color: #999999;
}

#MyMenu {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
}

#MyMenuItem {
  margin 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: silver;
}

#MyMenuItem:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}


/*  PROBLEMATIC CODE */

#MyMenuItem.active {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyMenu">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="MyMenuItem">1st Element</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="MyMenuItem">2nd Element</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="MyMenuItem" class="active">3rd Element</div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Codepen [Link](http://[http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/NpjEmP)

The menu seems to be working just fine, but when I try to add "active" class appears a space (margin?) between 2nd and 3rd element (after you hover on the 2nd):

I tried different approaches, but without results. All I have is this code:

```
#MyMenuItem.active{
    margin: 0 auto; //doesn't work
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Could you please take a look at it? Of course every advice how to do it better would be appreciated. Thank you!

[http://[http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/NpjEmP](http://[http://codepen.io/kriszap/pen/NpjEmP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is between all three elements and not just 2nd and 3rd element and its **NOT** because of the `active` class. Its because of **white spaces** and **newlines** in your `HTML` code.

First you need to know that there are multiple problems in your code which are listed below:

**1-** You are missing a colon `:` after `margin` at line `margin 0;` inside `CSS` code for `#MyMenuItem`

**2-** You are using the same `id` for each `div` inside your menu. **Each id must be unique**. If you want to refer to each div inside menu, use **class** instead of **id**

**3-** Don't use `div` inside `a` tags. (Not Recommended)

Here's a simpler and better version of your code with removed spaces between all three elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999999;  
}

#MyMenu {
width: 100%;
background-color: #333333;
text-align: center;
}

.MyMenuItem {
margin: 0;
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
color: silver;
}

.MyMenuItem:hover {
color: black;
background-color: white;
}

.active{
color: red;
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyMenu">
<a href="#" class="MyMenuItem">1st Element</a><a href="#" class="MyMenuItem">2nd Element</a><a href="#" class="MyMenuItem active">3rd Element</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys, you helped me a lot. I'm just trying to do everything "the hard may" and code everything manually in order to learn as much as possible.
@Yousaf: nice move with "MyMenuItem active" double class, works great. Just one question: what if I want to eliminate link for active class but still keep its background white (i.e. active)?

Comment: @KrisZap you mean you want to remove the link but keep the layout of third element ? if so, then just remove the `<a>` tag and replace it with `div` tag. Everything else remains same

Answer (score 2):

When you add `display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;` the elements are center horizontally and vertically and it will remove the spaces between the divs!

Change your

```
#MyMenu { width: 100%; background-color: #333333; text-align: center; }
```

to

```
#MyMenu { width: 100%; background-color: #333333; text-align: center; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
```

and it will have the result that you want!

Answer (score 1):

```
#MyMenuItem.active{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
}
```

try that, sometime padding messes with stuff,

also at the top of your css page try adding

```
body{
padding: 0px;
margin:  0px

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the whitespaces and newlines in your code. It's more or less a css bug.
If you still want a readable code, try putting all the whitespace in comments like this:

```
<div id="MyMenu">
<a href="#"><div id="MyMenuItem">1st Element</div></a><!--
--><a href="#"><div id="MyMenuItem">2nd Element</div></a><!--
--><a href="#"><div id="MyMenuItem" class="active">3rd Element</div></a>
</div>
```

I tested it in the codepen, it works.
For different solutions, see https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ but I like the "trick" with the comments best and most compatible.

### /edit

The problem is not your active class, it's the html. The space is already present before, you just can't see it, because it has the same colour as the background. But you can see it if you hover that tiny area with the mouse, then your mouse will become a cursor like hovering text and not a hand like hovering a link.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. First, the space you see is the space between the `<a>` tags, the actual space in the HTML code. In order to overcome this issue you need to build your UI properly.

Second: don't use `div` inside `a`, it should be the other way around. It will also solve your layout problem.

Third, you're using the same `id` for all your links. `id` must be unique! In your case you should use class instead.

[Example with a better layout](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZwyaJ)

Comment: Actually you may place div within a (HTML5), however it is not suggested (older HTML versions).